# The functions of haar_cascade in OpenCV don't work in VS Code

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've been learning the library OpenCV in Python for a while. But I have a problem with OpenCV on VS Code.

```
haar_cascade = CascadeClassifier("XML Files/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
faces_rect = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale()
```

The codes you see above are not detected especially in VS Code. I have the IDE PyCharm as well and those functions work on it but I don't like PyCharm as much as VS Code.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

By the way I should say that all of the functions of OpenCV work. Except the codes above.

Comment: `assert os.path.exists("XML Files/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")` and report back what that does -- where is the traceback? please review [ask] and maybe [mre]

Comment: it's done nothing.

Comment: and what's the result of `haar_cascade.empty()`? if that says False, that would be good. True would mean the loading failed. -- [edit] your post, add the complete traceback. this is required. please review [mre]

Comment: That function said the result was False. By the way I'm new at here. What's wrong with my post? I don't know what to rewrite my post.

Comment: hm wait, I misunderstood (or didn't I?)... you don't actually have any issues running the code, you're just asking because your IDE makes red squiggles? that is not considered "don't work". please browse previous questions. this (vscode and intellisense for opencv) is asked frequently.